# /autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGMKj.png)

```
D:\jasmin\laravel\shop>php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(D:\jasmin\laravel\shop/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\jasmin\laravel\shop\artisan on line 18

Warning: require(D:\jasmin\laravel\shop/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\jasmin\laravel\shop\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'D:\jasmin\laravel\shop/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\jasmin\xamp\php\PEAR') in D:\jasmin\laravel\shop\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\jasmin\laravel\shop/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\jasmin\xamp\php\PEAR') in D:\jasmin\laravel\shop\artisan on line 18
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run from command line

```
composer install 
or composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

**Composer Update**

You just need to run `composer update` to update your dependencies as they are specified in this file: `composer.json`. The command will generate `vendor/autoload.php`, too.

> **[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2#install-composer)**
>
> Laravel utilizes Composer to manage its dependencies. First, download a copy of the `composer.phar`. Once you have the PHAR archive, you can either keep it in your local project directory or move to `usr/local/bin` to use it globally on your system.
>
> On Windows, you can use the Composer [Windows installer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe).